# How to prevent textpos' textblock environment from inserting \par?

Tags: line-breaking, textpos

The following MWE confirms what `textpos` documentation says:

> The {textblock} environment will most often be used in vertical mode. If
>   it is called in horizontal (ie, paragraph) mode, however, it will silently create a
>   paragraph break by inserting a \par command before the environment; it remains
>   in vertical mode after the environment is finished.

Anyway, is there a way to prevent `textblock` environment to insert `\par`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textpos}
%
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\textheight}
%
\begin{document}
Foo
\begin{textblock}{1}(0,-0.2)
  Bar
\end{textblock}
Foo
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well this doesn't stop it issuing `\par` but it stops that `\par` ending the current paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textpos}
%
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\textheight}
%
\begin{document}
Foo
\vadjust{\begin{textblock}{1}(0,-0.2)
  Bar
\end{textblock}}
Foo
\end{document}
```