# Unwanted vertical shift of the textblock environment (textpos)

Tags: textpos

Here is MWE showing my problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\TPGrid{1}{1}

\begin{document}
  Line 1
  \begin{textblock}{1}(0,0)
    My overlay
  \end{textblock}
  Line 2
\end{document}
```

After building this document you can see, that the "Line 2" line gets printed partially over the "Line 1".

My question is: How to avoid this vertical shift?

Please, don't propose to add `\vspace{...}`, since for my purposes I need exact positioning (animation in `beamer`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textblocks are really supposed to be used in vertical mode, and a textblock forces a new paragraph if it starts in horizontal mode, so this is to some extent unsupported territory.  The TeXnical reason (thinking about this briefly) is that the `textblock` results in the ‘Line 2’ becoming separated, within the paragraph, from the ‘Line 1’ above it, so that TeX ‘forgets’ that it's in the middle of a paragraph, and so that has to add inter-paragraph spacing (ie, there isn't an upward vertical shift here, as much as a lack of the downward inter-paragraph space which TeX would otherwise add).

However it wouldn’t be unreasonable in this situation, nor necessarily particularly hard, for textpos instead to adjust spacing and penalties so that a textblock in horizontal mode ends up acting more like a `\par` (that would be me, editing it).  That's not going to happen immediately, though.

The most robust solution in this case, though, and with the current version of textpos, would be to move the textblock, somehow/somewhere, so that it ends up between paragraphs.  It'll be happier there!  In the beamer context (though I don't have much experience with beamer), it might be that putting the textblock (or textblocks?) all together at the beginning of the frame, might be worth a look.

I've added [an issue in the repo](https://bitbucket.org/nxg/textpos/issues/16/).  Thanks for reporting this.

*Edit*: clarified 'wouldn't be unreasonable' remark.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and for the issue. I'm totally OK with the new paragraph. In fact I also tried to put \par prior to \begin{textblock} manually. My concern is only the unexpected upward shift. (\begin{textblock} becomes something like \par\vspace{-1.1...mm}).

Comment: I've adjusted the answer slightly: it would be better for a textblock in horizontal mode to act more like a `\par`.  Right now, it makes only a rather half-hearted attempt at this (because it's not really supported, and this is better than nothing).

Comment: Oooh, I've just noticed David Carlisle's [answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276433/), where he suggests using `\vadjust`.

Comment: Could you please change the type of the issue from enhancement to bug? I added clarifications. Again: This is not about the '\par' being inserted. It is about this weird upward shift. It comes in the vertical mode too. Thank you!!

Comment: \vadjust completely solves my problem! Please, add it to your answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: I've created a 1.10b1 release -- see the issue.

Comment: @BorisBrodski did you have a chance to try the 1.10b1 beta release, to see if it does address the issues you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, it works flawlessly in both horizontal and vertical modes. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent -- thanks for testing.  Then I'll release 1.10 shortly, after tidying up a couple of other things.

Answer (score 1):

Put apart the `textblock`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\TPGrid{1}{1}

\begin{document}
  Line 1

  Line 2
  \begin{textblock}{1}(0,0)
    My overlay
  \end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple, :) but unfortunately not possible in my case. E.g. with large paragraphs the overlay will end up on the wrong page. In my case, the beamer overlay specification <+> will not work correctly. Is where any other solution without moving textblock?